# Got Stuck at a point while reading Group Theory I by M. Suzuki

Tags: group-theory

I am reading Group Theory I by M. Suzuki (1982). I have got stuck at a point. I would appreciate if one can help me in this regard.

At page no. 76 he defines transvection as a linear transformation of $SL(V)$ which is not identity but fixes all the elements of a hyperplane $H$. After Theorem 9.5 he wishes to prove that if $t$ is a transvection, then $t$ can be represented by a matrix $B_{12}=I+E_{12}$ with respect to some basis $\{v_i\}$. For this he argues as follows:

By definition $t$ fixes every element of a hyperplane $H$. Also there is an element $u$ of $V$ such that $t(u) \neq u$; thus $V=H+Fu$. Since $t \in SL(V)$, $t(u)-u \in H$.....

Now, I do not understand why $t(u)-u \in H$, if $t \in SL(V)$.

Here $V$ denotes a vector space over a field $F$, $E_{12}$ is the matrix containing $1$ at $(12)^{th}$ position and $0$ elsewhere, $SL(V)$ the set of all linear transformations on $V$ with determinant $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $t(u)$ can be represented as $t(u) = \lambda u + h$, where $\lambda \in F$ and $h \in H$. It is then not hard to see that $\det t = \lambda$. Then, since $t \in SL(V)$, $\lambda$ must equal $1$, and so $t(u) - u = h \in H$.

To see that $\det t = \lambda$ you can pick a basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ in $H$. Then $(e_1, \ldots, e_n, u)$ is a basis in $V$, and the matrix of $t$ in this basis is $$\left(\begin{matrix}I_n & * \\ 0 & \lambda\end{matrix}\right),$$
where $*$ are the coordinates of $h$ in basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$. From this it is clear that $\det t = \lambda$.